# Why exactly is the Guassian filter a low-pass filter?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, lowpass-filter

In image processing, a [Guassian filter](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm) is used to blur an image. A low-pass filter is a filter that attenuates the high frequencies, preserving only smooth variations in the provided image. Is a Guassian filter a low-pass filter because it smooths the edges (or, in general, the parts of the image where there is a high variation of the intensity)? Why exactly is the Guassian filter a low-pass filter?

Answer (score 2):

Because the Fourier transform of Gaussian in the spatial/temporal domain is also a Gaussian in the frequency domain. Since a Gaussian drops off rapidly with frequency, it's a low pass filter.

Comment: are you serious?